# Access static class directly or cache it?

Tags: c#, caching, unity-game-engine

I know that it's better to cache a component if you use it often during runtime. How about if I cache a component as a static variable and access it during runtime? Let me give you an example:

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AudioManager audioManager;

    void Awake()
    {
        audioManager = this;
    }
}
```

Then if I access it from another class, should I use `AudioManager.audioManager` or cache it beforehand (speaking in the terms of performance)?

P.S. Let me know if something isn't clear.

Edit: I guess I don't know what the hell I'm doing regarding Singletons, but to make it clear, this is a newbie question regarding performance:

1) `_audioManager = AudioManager.audioManager` in Awake and then use `_audioManager.someVariable` in Update

VS

2) `AudioManager.audioManager.someVariable` in Update

Comment: Are you looking for [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) ? Do you need multiple instance of `AudioManager` or you ever need only one instance?

Comment: You should use property with non-public setter to avoid `AudioManager.audioManager = null`  case somewhere outside. If under caching you mean deferred execution, then use `Lazy<>`. If you need single object, then use `static` provider or [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, just one instance.

Comment: @Revolter Then my link should help you

Comment: I mean
`_audioManager = AudioManager.audioManager;` in Awake
and then use `_audioManager.someVariable` in Update

VS

`AudioManager.audioManager.someVariable` in Update

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, thanks, I'll look into it, got a hard time understanding Singletons for now

Comment: this has premature optimization written all over it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You don't need to cache your own component for speed in any case*.  A component won't pay a performance penalty for accessing *itself*.

The use case you may be thinking of is caching access to other components or objects so that you don't have to do lookup with GetComponent or GetComponentWithChildren.  That does save time, but it's not a complex pattern: just do the lookup the first time you encounter the other component or gameobject, store it in a field inside this component, and you're good:

```
 class Example: MonoBehavior
 {

     public GameObject _TargetCharacter;
     private Transform _cachedTransform;
     private Animator  _cachedAnimator;

     void Awake()
     {
      if (_TargetCharacter != null)
      {
          _cachedTransform = _TargetCharacter.transform;
          _cachedAnimator = _TargetCharacter.GetComponent<Animator>();
       }
     }


     void Update()
     {
         DoSomething (_cachedTransform, _cachedAnimator);
     }
 }
```

GetComponent and GetComponentInChildren are comparatively expensive you do don't want to do them every frame. However direct access to something set as a field is not expensive there is no need to cache it.

And making it s Singleton: in this context, you would need to make a separate class which is NOT a Component and have that be the singleton - you can't prevent somebody from attaching lots of a given MonoBehavior to things in the Unity Editor so you don't want to assume there's only one of the component floating around. In the AudioManager example, you'd have to assume that many different components might all be looking at the same AudioManager.

Here a good example [comparing shared behavior using Singletons vs shared behavior in a static class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static). Two means to the same end, with slightly different strengths and weaknesses.

**Update** In response to OP's comment below:

If the point of the original code is to gain speed using the common Unity caching trick, it's not needed. If the point is, as OP suggests in comment below, to make the manager into a 'service provider' that other classes can call there are two routes to go:

The standard unity trick would be to add the caching behavior to the *other* classes that need to get to the AudioManager.  For example:

```
class SomeOtherComponent: MonoBehavior
{
    AudioManager _manager;
    void Awake()
    {
    AudioManager[] AllAudioManagers = GetComponents<AudioManager>();
    if (AllAudioManagers.Count == 1)
        {
        _manager = AllAudioManagers[0];
        }
    else
        {
         throw new RuntimeError ("Expecting one (and only one) AudioManager in scene");
        } 
    }
}
```

Switching to a proper Singleton implementation more or less amounts to just taking the boilerplate in the `Awake` method above and centralizing into the singleton class, allowing you to replace it.

For an extended discussion of the singleton pattern in unity try [this book](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/c-game-programming-cookbook-for-unity-3d-jeff-w-murray/1118136212?cm_mmc=google%20product%20search-_-q000000633-_-9781466581401pla-_-book_45up-_-q000000633-_-9781466581401&ean=9781466581401&isbn=9781466581401&kpid=9781466581401&r=1)

Comment: `You don't need to cache your own component for speed in any case. A component won't pay a performance penalty for accessing itself` Do you have proof of that? You don't pay for calling `transform.position` instead of caching your own transform?

Comment: `component.transform` is using reflection to get to the transform from the parent game object, so you do want to cache that. But if you declare your own fields and access them (as OP did) there's no savings. Check the wording on http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Performance_Optimization.html

Comment: @theodox, I understand there are certain patterns and the safe way to do something. But in my case, I  have a single gameobject with AudioManager script on it, that will hold references to a bunch of AudioSources. And nobody will touch the code or the project besides me. I will not add a different AudioManager.

I made it this way so I could just call AudioManager.audioManager.SomeAudioClip.Play() from any other script to play sounds, without using GetComponent and GameObject.Find.

Comment: Many people seem to suggest that I implement a Singleton pattern, but my code is working as is, and I'm trying to understand why would I implement it any differently in my case. What could go wrong with my code, taking in consideration the way I'm using it?

Comment: The short version: your code as posted works, but gives no extra benefits because you're 'caching' something that you already have fast access to.  The singleton pattern is important for people who need to make sure many components share access to one shared state (for example, you would wan't a bunch of AI to all use the same game map data not separate copies that could get out of sync).  You original code is a bit misleading since it looks like a typical singleton but (unless I'm mistaken) it's just an effort to get public access to your class. See edit above

Comment: @Revolter If I may, never code like only you is going to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I live by a simple rule, if I am going to be calling a component a lot of times, more than 5, then I cache it. The same rule I apply to Singletons. If it is only one call then I just use the `Singleton.getInstance()`.

---

#### What you should be really caching

Unity Components such as [**Transform**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html).

The logic behind caching things like `Transform` comes from looking at the documentation. Transform is not a variable but a property, which happens to contain getters and setters. These are hidden from you, but that's the way it is implemented. This property happens to be written in C or C++. Therefore this will cost you on performance.